# Can I just add Identity to upgraded project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a project where I needed to make changes to. It was made with asp 4, but they disabled user accounts. They had commented most things related to it (account controller, ...) and removed most assemblies. After a fair share of errors and problems with trying to activate it all, so I decided to upgrade the project to mvc 5.

My question now is, how do I change the membership to identity. Is it simply adding Identity to the solution, and changing the account controller? Or is there more to it then that.

Comment: There was an [article](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity) for that.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it!